Gitlab pipeline can run even though I stop the gitlab-runner
I am using gitlab-runner to run jobs on my Gitlab project. I disabled Instance runner and only allow Project runners to run. In Project runners, I create a runner (docker mode) and register it on my EC2. However, after I stop gitlab-runner with this command gitlab-runner stop and I retry the job on my project, I still see it's running. In the output, it's showing that it's running with the runner on my EC2. How can it happen?
I expect that after I stop gitlab-runner, the job on Gitlab will be stuck and wait for the runner to be up again.
